# How to stop DHCP , DNS WINS roles in window 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

There are few roles defined in window 2003 like

DHCP
DNS SERVER
WINS

I want to stop these roles as they are causing problem with some DNS
How can i stop those roles or i have to remove those roles

Answer (score 1):

You could start by just stopping those services and see if that solves your problem.  Administrative Tools - Services  turn off DHCP Server, Wins Server and Domain Naming Service.

Comment: +1, but I'm also interested in what kind of problems the OP has experienced, as I suspect that stopping these will fix the symptoms but not necessarily the cause.

Comment: I agree - though my guess is he's got a new DHCP/DNS server in place and the problem is both of them are handing out leases and DNS.  OP let us know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start/stop services through their configuration windows: Start: Programs: Administrative Tools: DHCP:  - Right Mouse Click: All tasks: Restart


In addition to the GUI based solution, you can also start/stop the services through commandline:

```
#>sc query | find /i "_NAME"
#>sc stop dhcp
#>sc start dhcp
```